# Error: "Import Pandas" fails on Jupyter notebook in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am having an issue trying to import pandas on my Jupyter notebook using Python 3.10. I am using a MacOS computer with VSCode as my IDE.

I have installed pandas on my machine using Homebrew `brew install pandas` and it works just fine when I use `import pandas` in my IDE. However, it fails in Jupyter.

I open jupyter as normal with `jupyter notebook`. I then attempt the simple command `import pandas` I get an error message that says:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import pandas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I did a quick search on Stack and across Google and everybody tells me to run `!pip install pandas` in the Jupyter notebook but since I am using PHP3.10, I have opted for `!pip3 install pandas`. When I do this, Jupyter tells me:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Users/daveshields/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in /Users/daveshields/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in /Users/daveshields/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /Users/daveshields/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/daveshields/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)
```

I close Jupyter and then open it again and attempt `import pandas` and I get the exact same message. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening? I am doing the Python Master Course by Ardit Sulce on Udemy but I can't progress any further in the course until I can figure this out. TYIA.

Dave Shields

Comment: Inside a notebook when using `pip`, you no longer want to use it in combination with an exclamation point. Anything advising that for `pip` or `conda` now is outdated. The new magics were added to help install things via pip or conda to the environment backing the current Jupyter session, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). Using the modern magic command the variation to run inside your notebook would be `%pip install pandas`. It's not a magic pill though. It seems you are having permissions errors.

Comment: In fact, most times because automagics are *generally* on by default, you'll get behind-the-scenes the magic command for `pip` or `conda` if you use **no symbol at all**. Explicitly adding `%` in front of `pip` or `conda` makes it more obvious to you and others that you are using the magic command. In short avoid the exclamation point with either `pip` or `conda` going forward. (I think use of the magic command also obviates the need for the `3` after `pip` because it knows to use what is being used in the notebook from `%pip` alone.) All that may not help you much here, but could elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much to Wayne!

Amazingly the `%pip install pandas` worked! I did that and it installed pandas and numpy.

I ran `import pandas` and then `df1 = pandas.DataFrame([[2,4,6],[10,30,30]])`.

After that I was able to successfully use `print(df1)` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import sys   
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas
```

If you already have Pandas in your system and still not able to load it then :

```
import sys  
sys.path.append('your-path')
```